# remove the extra column that comes datagrid

Tags: silverlight-4.0

how  to  remove the  extra  column that comes  default in datagrid  silverlight 4.0

is there any good links to  designing(css) data grid in silverlight 4.0

thanks in advance.
 prince

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take total control over what columns are rendered in a Silverlight DataGrid, you need to define your own 'Columns' collection.  For example:

```
<sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ...>
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="firstColumn".... />
        ....
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

Hope that helps